# How to invoke non-default constructors when using vector resize?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, c++03

Suppose I create a class

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int numofCars, int someValue);

private: 
    vector<Car> carList;
}

Foo::Foo(int numofCars, int someValue)
{
    carList.resize(numofCars);
}
```

My understanding is that after resize the vector (`carList` was an empty `vector`) will become a list of `Car` objects by calling the default constructor.

Can I specify the constructor of the `Car` object being called? For example, instead of calling `Car()`, I want to call `Car(int Value)`?

Comment: your code isn't legal c++..

Comment: Read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/).

Comment: You can use `emplace_back` to add a new element to a vector calling the constructor you want, and avoiding any copies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. [(live example)](http://ideone.com/dAemtG)

```
carList.resize(numofCars, Cars(42));
```

[see more information](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize).

---

If you're unwilling to make unnecessary copy, there's a bit complex code.

```
carList.reserve(numofCars);
for (int i = 0; i < numofCars; i++)
    carList.emplace_back(42);
```

[(live example)](http://ideone.com/tF6LWq)

It's probably better, but it's *not* always efficient - if the cost of "1 creation + 10 copying" is less than the cost of "10 creation". It would be case-by-case.

Comment: This creates a temporary Car object, and then copies it into the new elements. Which is fine, if Car is cheap to copy.

Comment: @NeilKirk Yes. Even if `resize()` is simple, I hope I can find better solution >o<